# Spatial Join by radius?

Tags: spatial-join

I am using the spatial join tool.

Is there a spatial join tool that I can specify a certain radius and only join the features in that radius?

Perhaps I would have to crop the data to my radius then use spatial join.

Create a model, unless there is a tool that does this?

Comment: Which GIS software?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ArcGis the [Spatial Join tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) will do this with the Search Radius option:

> Search Radius (optional) Join features within this distance of a
>   target feature will be considered for the spatial join

[image]

Comment: Yes arcMap 10.3 I did not even see that radius section down there. Thank you very much. I should be more perceptive